# What are all the machine learning methods that can be used for Predict?

Tags: machine-learning

When I'm writing code for the `Predict` function, it allows me to choose what method I want to use. There are 7 options available from the drop-down after I type in `Method ->`: `DecisionTree`, `GradientBoostedTrees`, `LinearRegression`, `NearestNeighbors`, `NeuralNetwork`, `RandomForest`, and `GaussianProcess`. Are there any other methods that can be used? I couldn't find any leads in the documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's all there under _Possible settings for Method include:_  in the _Details and Options_ section https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html unless the high priests know some hidden internal/undocumented methods. I tried making up some training data and doing `Trace[Predict[training, Method->"fake"]]` to see if there were any hidden `Methods` it was comparing "fake" to but nothing caught my eye.There is an undocumented `Method` in `Classify` though called `"PriorBaseline"`

Comment: "SupportVectorMachine", "NaiveBayes", and "MarkovSomethingOrOther" are three others that I can (mostly) recall.